# In css, how to disregard the styles a class

Tags: css

If I have 2 css classes on a element like this

```html
<a class="class1 class2" href="#">Link</a>
```

Is there any way I can tell the web page to disregard the styles of class1 and use the styles of only class2?

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just simply take out the class you don't want?

Comment: Are you looking for [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)?

Comment: try using jquery mehods like **addClass()** and **removeClass()**.
this will definitely work

Comment: You can: Remove a class, create a new class that has the styles you want, create a new class that moves unwanted styles from the class you are trying to override then add that new class to other elements you want to have those styles, you can use the `important` tag as moose suggested, if you REALLY want, you can use JavaScript as Suyash suggests (however I personally wouldn't apply that method unless it is absolutely needed), you can insert a new attribute into your html tag and set your styles there (`style="{float: left;}"` for example) and I am sure other methods exist too

Comment: Avoid `!important` or inline styling unless you _absolutely_ have to.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvxeNr

GO to this link
Hope this will help you.
I have done it considering general case

Comment: I am using kendo mvc grid which assigns k-button css class to the buttons. I want to use icons instead of buttons and I am able to add additional classes to the buttons but this k-button class is appearing on top of the classes that I have added. How can I make the web page use my added classes styles only and not k-button styles.And I cannot remove k-button class because the functionality will not work

Comment: Well in that case I would use inline styling. Although you should typically try to stay away from it, sometimes it is necessary and it should override external CSS properties that the `k-button` class is setting, unless that class uses `!important` in properties you are trying to change, in which case you'll have to add `!important` to the styles you are trying to implement as specificity with precedence wins. The only other way to change it would be to use JavaScript

Comment: Here are a couple links that explains specificity and the `!important` exception: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. The second link (mozilla) even talks about how you should try to implement specificity so that it can be most effective and cause the least amount of issues when building a website

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible in general, but you can overwrite the properties:

```
.class1 {
    margin-top: 2em;
}

.class2 {
    margin-top: inherit;
}
```

You can also make declarations more specific:

```
.class1.class2 {
    /* now set your values here */
}
```

Or use `!important`, though it makes maintaining the CSS a nightmare.

As a sidenote: If you do not want to use declarations from `class1`, why are you setting the value in the first place? If you are using the class for JavaScript selectors, consider using different classes for styling and JavaScript purposes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the same properties in both files !important can help.

```
<a class="class1 class2">this text will be red</a>

.class1 {
    color:red !important;
}
.class2 {
    color:blue;
}
```

Normally, the latter class in CSS file is what you can see.

```
<a class="class1 class2">this text will be blue</a>
<a class="class2 class1">this text will be blue</a>

.class1 {
    color:red;
}
.class2 {
    color:blue;
}
```

Comment: I prefer specificity over `!important` myself.

Comment: @hungerstar I agree, however there are cases where you customize some existing products and the CSS is already specific and can't be edited, forcing us to use `!important`. My guess is that could be OPs case.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few CSS only approaches you could do and they involve specificity.

**1 - Use the Cascade**

```css
.class1 {
    color: red;
}
.class2 {
    color: blue;
}
```

Since `.class2` appeared later in the stylesheet, any of it's properties that appeared in `.class1` will win out.

**2 - Use Specificity** - [more details on specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

```css
a.class2 {} /* specificty = 11 */
.class1 {} /* specificity = 10 */
```

Making your selector more specific than another allows it override other style declarations even if it appears before another CSS selector in the stylesheet.

There are other ways to increase the specificity but if you use the approach of increasing specificity, remember to increase it as little as possible. That way your styles remain more flexible and don't end up littering you CSS with a ton of ids and/or `!important` declarations.

[Specificity Calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)

There is another option but I tend not to advocate that option.